# How many Homomorphisms can be between $Z_6$ to $Z_{18}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, combinatorics, group-theory, finite-groups

How many Homomorphisms can be between $Z_6$ to $Z_{18}$?
and the most important: What is the algorithm for calculating, step by step?

Comment: Hey guys,I sincerely thank you all. know i am trying to Implement the algorithm in $Z$x$Z_6$ to $Z_2$x$Z_{60}$, and i can't.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We must know where the generator goes,

$f$ be a Homo such that $f(1)=a,f(6)=f(0)=6f(1)=6a=0$ in $Z_{18}$

so $a=3,6,9,12,15,0$

so Including trivial homo, we see there are $6$ Homomorphism

Comment: How you implement this algorithm in $Z \times Z_6 $to $Z_2 \times Z_{60}$?

Answer (score 4):

Say we have a homomorphism, $\varphi:Z_n \rightarrow Z_m$. Given that $x \in Z_n$ is determined by $1_{Z_n}$, in the sense
$$
x=\underbrace{1_{Z_m}+1_{Z_m}+\cdots+1_{Z_m}}_{x \text{ times}}
$$
the properties of the homomorphism force the image to be entirely determined by the image of $1_{Z_n}$ under $\varphi$. Why? Observe, let $x \in Z_{n}$
$$
\varphi(x)=\varphi(\underbrace{1_{Z_m}+1_{Z_m}+\cdots+1_{Z_m}}_{x \text{ times}})=\underbrace{\varphi(1_{Z_n})+\varphi(1_{Z_n})+\cdots+\varphi(1_{Z_n})}_{x \text{ times}}
$$ 
All that matters is $\varphi(1_{Z_n})$, so if $1_{Z_n}$ maps to $a \in Z_{m}$ then $x\in Z_n$ must map to $xa$. Now two facts determine all the rest:

$1$. If $|x|=n$, then $|\varphi(x)|$ must divide $n$.

$2$. Lagrange's Theorem: In any finite group, the order of a subgroup must divide the order of the group. (The converse is **not** true!)

The two together imply that $|a|$, the image of $\varphi(1_{Z_n})$, must divide not only $n$ (by Lagrange's Theorem) but also $m$ (by Property $1$).

Now given we want a homomorphism $\varphi:Z_n\rightarrow Z_m$, which numbers $a$ are these? Then how many homomorphisms are there total? Finally, to see the bigger picture, what is $\text{gcd}(6,18)$? Is this a coincidence? What does this mean?

Answer (score 2):

A generator of $\mathbb{Z}_6$ must go to an element $z\in\mathbb{Z}_{18}$ such that $6z=0$. These elements are …

Now, given $z\in\mathbb{Z}_{18}$ such that $6z=0$, we can define a morphism $f\colon \mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{Z}_{18}$ by $f(n)=nz$. Since $f(6n)=6nz=n(6z)=0$, the kernel of $f$ contains $6\mathbb{Z}$ and so … (apply the homomorphism theorem).